# Error: must have either extensions or value no both

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

he created a Consent resource profile through forge, with a test extension that only contains a String value.
When I try to validate the Consent resource, it gives me this error, but I do not know what it means.

**Profile**:

```
<StructureDefinition xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  <id value="Consent" />
  <meta>
    <lastUpdated value="2017-12-21T17:22:27.087+01:00" />
  </meta>
  <url value="http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/MyConsent" />
  <name value="Consent" />
  <status value="draft" />
  <date value="2017-12-19T09:08:41.006+01:00" />
  <description value="prueba&#xD;&#xA;" />
  <fhirVersion value="3.0.1" />
  <kind value="resource" />
  <abstract value="false" />
  <type value="Consent" />
  <baseDefinition value="http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/Consent" />
  <derivation value="constraint" />
  <differential>
    <element id="Consent.extension">
      <path value="Consent.extension" />
      <slicing>
        <discriminator>
          <type value="value" />
          <path value="url" />
        </discriminator>
        <rules value="open" />
      </slicing>
    </element>
    <element id="Consent.extension:pruebaExtension">
      <path value="Consent.extension" />
      <sliceName value="pruebaExtension" />
      <min value="1" />
      <type>
        <code value="Extension" />
        <profile value="http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/PruebaExtension" />
      </type>
    </element>
    <element id="Consent.identifier">
      <path value="Consent.identifier" />
      <min value="1" />
    </element>
  </differential>
</StructureDefinition>
```

Thanks

Comment: "extension":[
   {
  "url" : "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/PruebaExtension",
  "valueString" : "123456789"
 }
  ],

Comment: What's the extension definition look like?  Can you provide the full instance example